# HTTPS sites no longer load on my Android after installing cert to truststore

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, troubleshooting, certificates, https

I have a rooted Android 4.3 JellyBean. I was testing something and trying to install the certificate for Charles Proxy so I could sniff some SSL traffic. I was able to push the Charles certificate to /system/etc/security/cacerts and this allowed me to do what I wanted. However, ever since I did this, my browsers no longer load HTTPS sites. For example, Chrome gives me the "Your connection is not private" message.

Also, and not sure if this is normal, but when I look in Settings > Security > Trusted credentials, there are no System Certificates listed.

How can I fix whatever I did?

Comment: Did you __"pull"__ the Charles  certificate out of the /system/…/cacerts? Did you make a backup prior to pushing the cert to system?

Comment: i moved the cert to the sd card, remounted the system mount as RW, copied the cert file over to the cacerts dir, then rebooted. I didn't modify existing files so there was nothing to backup.

Comment: If you check the certificates directory again (e.g. with a root explorer): are there any files in, or is it empty now? If the other certs are still there: Does it start working again when you remove that other cert?

Answer (score 0):

"Whatever you did", you removed all of your trusted CA's (Certificate Authority).

Unfortunately I cannot help other than to say you should have well over 50-60 trusted CA's in that list (where you have none).